# Apply styling to dynamically created checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a collection of checkboxes which I got from bootstrap that appear more as buttons than checkboxes, but their checked status still toggles on clicks. I have a text input on the form that allows the user to add checkboxes with labels and values corresponding to the user input. All of the checkboxes are in the same `div` component.

I use javascript to dynamically create the new checkbox and append it to a `label`, which gets appended to the `div` containing the checkboxes. The new checkbox appears on the page, but without the styling, which is linked in the head of the html document. How can I apply the styling to the new checkbox?

Here is the javascript that I am using:

```
function addRestriction() {
                let userInput = document.getElementById("add_other").value; // get user input
                let newBox = document.createElement("input");
                newBox.type = "checkbox";
                newBox.autocomplete = 'off';
                newBox.name = 'diet_button';
                newBox.value = userInput;
                let newLabel = document.createElement("label");
                newLabel.class = "btn btn-outline-secondary active";
                newLabel.appendChild(newBox);
                newLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput));
                document.getElementById('diet_restrictions').appendChild(newLabel);
                document.getElementById('add_other').value = '';
            }
```

Comment: try newLabel.className= "btn btn-outline-secondary active";

Comment: Adding a new element with a class will apply all CSS immediately. Are you certain that the class names, element hierarchies and CSS rules are correctly matching up? Use F12 dev tools to find out. What if you had those checkboxes on the page statically? Still not applying the styles? Any other elements that use the styles?

Comment: element.class is the wrong thing to use either className or classList.add()

Comment: `newLabel.class = "btn btn-outline-secondary active";` ==> Change to `newLabel.className = "btn btn-outline-secondary active";` or `newLabel.classList.add("btn", "btn-outline-secondary", "active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers are correct:

```
element.className = "new-class"
```

Will set this elements only class name to "new-class"
While:

```
element.classList.add("new-class")
```

Will add a new class to already existing set of classes. This feature might be useful in case you are going to further expand classes in your newly created checkboxes.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsjfz514/1/) shows the differences.

1. [.className ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
2. [.classList ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. A little weird that the field for setting the class attribute isn't just class but oh well.